# SpriteKit Everyplay Live Preview faceCam Jerky

Tags: sprite-kit, everyplay

I am using Everyplay (3rd party lib) to record thru front camera in my Spritekit game. But in the latest SDK version, the camera display is very choppy and jerky. I have tried:

```
[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] setWorkaroundFrameJerking:YES];
```

But seems to be not doing anything. Still jerky. Anybody have a solution for this problem?

EDIT: Just to be clear, it is the small preview camera that is jerky. Not the recording itself.